# Netsuite connector in mule "returnSearchColumns" attribute

Tags: json, xml, mule, netsuite

I created a saved search of "items" in netsuite.

```
<netsuite:search config-ref="NetSuite__Login_Authentication" searchRecord="ITEM_ADVANCED" bodyFieldsOnly="false" returnSearchColumns="true" doc:name="NetSuite"/>
<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
```

When 'returnSearchColumns' is set to "true", receiving the below exception. If this attribute is set to false, there is no exception but response is missing the columns selected.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.mule.module.netsuite.RecordTypeEnum.ITEM
```

Also, received 'ConsumerIterator' object as response from netsuite and used "Object to JSON" transformer right after netsuite connector. The response received is an array of item objects.

1) Is there a way to convert this payload into XML format? Both object to XML and JSON to XML are not giving entire XML.
2) How to avoid the above mentioned illegal argument exception ?

Answer (score 0):

1) object-to-xml should convert all fields to XML, or you could try something like Dataweave. What exactly is missing?

2) There is no type called 'ITEM'. You have to use one mentioned in this list: http://mulesoft.github.io/netsuite-connector/6.0.1/java/org/mule/module/netsuite/RecordTypeEnum.html such as 'INVENTORY_ITEM '

Comment: RecordTypeEnum.ITEM is what it is referring when 'returnSearchColumns' attribute is set to 'true'. Could this be a problem with netsuite connector itself as I am using only pre-defined transformers and not custom ones?